# msi rolling back and no error logged

Tags: installation, webserver, windows-installer

I am having a problem installing an msi on to a windows 2008 web server. The exact same msi previously installed successfully. The msi is for a .net 4.0 web application that I have created and being installed in to IIS.

What happens is that the msi seems to be installing correctly, and it reaches 0 seconds remaining on the progress bar, then suddenly it starts rolling back. I checked the event viewer for information on this but none appeared there, to assist with getting to the bottom of what the issue may be.

As the msi previously installed without issue on to the box, I believe the problem may be to do with a change to the server rather than to do with the msi.

Anyone experience this before or have an idea as to where I may be able to find more information as to why the msi installer is rolling back?

---

Ok, what I have done with the help of Bogdan Mitrache reply was to compare logs from a successfull server and the server causing the problem and this is the section where I found the error to occur:

```
FAILED: -2147024864
FAILED: -2147024864
Custom Action failed with code: '32'
Custom Action failed with code: '32'
Custom Action completed with return code: '32'
Info 1903. Scheduling reboot operation: Deleting file << root directory >>\TBD2D0E.tmp. Must reboot to complete operation.
Info 1903. Scheduling reboot operation: Deleting file << root directory >>\TBD2ED3.tmp. Must reboot to complete operation.
Info 1903. Scheduling reboot operation: Deleting file << root directory >>\TBD2F41.tmp. Must reboot to complete operation.
```

And then at the very end of the process:

```
Return value 3.
```

I have done searching on the internet but I have found no concrete reason as to why the above may be occuring. Anyone have further information on the above, or where i may look?

Answer (score 7):

The best method to see exactly why the MSI package fails is to create a verbose log, using this command line:  **msiexec /i "msi path" /L*V "debug.log"**
The log should contain more details about the cause of the rollback. As you suspected probably you have a duplicate IIS web site/app that conflicts with the package.

Comment: I have this log, what should I be looking for in it as it's rather large in size?

Comment: Usually errors are easily located in the log if you search for "Return value 3". Successful actions have the "Return value 1" message. Here are more details about how you can read a verbose log: http://blogs.technet.com/b/paulpaa/archive/2010/02/05/how-to-read-a-windows-installer-verbose-log.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have updated my question with the information I got from what you outlined, could you take a look and consider what my next steps in resolving this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The return code mentioned in the log means this:  "**The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**". The reboot messages are automatically included by Windows Installer when a file that needs to be updated is currently in use.

According to Windows Installer standards, the return code of a custom action must be 0 to be considered it executed successfully. Any return code different from 0 is considered failure.

What you should do is to add another custom action, scheduled in the beginning of the installation, that stops any services/applications that could use resources updated by the package.

Comment: That's a really good idea and might be exactly what I need to include. So the first step would be to stop any services/applications that could use resources updated by the package. All the resources should be in the one folder. Question is, how do I do this??

Comment: Here is thread were this topic is debated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251218/how-to-stop-a-running-process-during-an-msi-based-un-install

Comment: Again, thank you. I am currently looking in to this. Is there any way to know what file is being used by another process? It does not seem apparent by the log and as the msi installs a large number of files, it would be difficult to track down.

Comment: Also where would I find a list of the return code to error description mapping? eg 32 = The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. I cant find it on the internet.

Comment: I'm using "Visual c++ error lookup" tool. Here are more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh0w11(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should be using virtual machines with snapshots to rule out changes to the environment vs changes to the installer.  And you should certainly be logging and reading your windows installer log.